# Backup solution (includes tape backup)

Tags: backup, tape

What would be the best Linux based solution for backup (later maybe tape backup too). There are Bacula, Amanda, and others. 
Any suggestions which to learn ?

(Now I use compressed tarballs simply)

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend looking into bacula. It does take quite a bit of work to get it up and running, however once up it is rock solid. If you need any assisstance let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend Bacula. We are using it for backing up sensitive information for several clients with between 2 and 15TB of data. Bacula also helped detect subtle data corruption caused by a faulty LTO4 tape drive.

Answer (score 2):

The "best" is the one that fully suits your needs and provides reliable restore capabilities. Just don't forget to factor off-site into the equation.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently was facing same decision and I went with Amanda. It was hard choice because both are good and both have weaknesses. So, my decision boiled down to personal preferences, i.e. GUI vs. command line, dependency on database or no database, etc. My advice go with one that fits you better - they are both good.

Comment: And are you satisfied with Amanda ? It seems to me, it's GUI is only in the commercial version.

Comment: I completely satisfied with Amanda's functionality and I prefer command line interface for setting thing up. As with any backup system, you just need to set it up once and then it should work with little human interaction. So, it may take less time to set it up through the GUI but CLI gives more control. But again, this is just personal preference and both systems are good. And yes, they have commercial version that offers even more, so it keeps some extra options open.

Comment: unfortunately its hard to explain to a non-technical client about how zmanda is a rock solid service with a command line tool. They just say, oooh isnt the the web-bacula web interface all clicky clicky nice. So bacula wins the "client sell" test.

Answer (score 1):

I have eared about [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) which is simple to use, and does the job well.